# Name of this CSS syntax?

Tags: javascript, css, web

Can someone please tell me what this syntax is called, I tried looking it up but didn't find it. Im refering to how the player class seems to be extended i.e. ".player:fullscreen". Thank you.

```
.player {
    max-width: 750px; /n
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* This css is only applied when fullscreen is active */
.player:fullscreen {
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.player:-webkit-full-screen {
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No need to explain the technicalities I can read up myself, just need the appropriate terminology. Cheers.

Comment: "Psuedo-class" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

`:fullscreen` is a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).